# fail2ban block webrequests containing a given string

Tags: linux, networking, fail2ban

I want to configure my system to reject all web requests that contain inappropriate words *(I won't be using the actual string here, but an example string that is representative of the implementation for obvious reasons)*.

I have the following configuration in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```
[DEFAULT]
bantime = 1d
[sshd]
enabled = true     
filter    = sshd
banaction = iptables
backend   = systemd
maxretry  = 5
findtime  = 1d
bantime   = 2d
ignoreip  = 127.0.0.1/8

[word-filter]
enabled = true
filter = word-filter
maxretry = 0
bantime = 1m
```

And a configuration of the same pattern *(but with different words)* in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/word-filter.conf`

```
[Definition]
failregex = .*Hello.*World|.*test.*
```

When I try to reload fail2ban it gives an error in `systemctl status fail2ban` and when I try to run `fail2ban-regex /example/file` `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/word-filter.conf` It gives the error `ERROR: No failure-id group in '.*Hello.*World.*|.*test.*`

How could I fix this?

Comment: This is just a guess but I think it's saying that you need to capture <HOST> in the failregex (every f2b rule I looked at in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/` that I looked at either had `<HOST>` in a fail2regex or in a before include file) - that's what fail2ban is all about, capturing a host address so it an be banned.   BTW, the .* at the starts and ends of the alternations aren't needed, can be shortened to just `Hello.*World|test`

Comment: BTW, web request filter rules should probably be based on an existing rule for apache or nginx or whatever httpd you're using. Would certainly be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Error `No failure-id group in` means that regex doesn't contain any ID (like `<ADDR>`, `<HOST>`, `<CIDR>`, `<SUBET>`, `<F-ID>...</F-ID>` etc), so if regex will match, fail2ban would not know how the offender should be identified as well as who exactly needs to be banned, if `maxretry` gets reached for the ID.
For IP based processing it is typically `<ADDR>`.

Comment: I would like for this to work for every site. It should ban the site that it detects the string on. How would I implement this?